# How to check Bind 9.10 actual configuration settings?

Tags: dns, bind

I want to play with Bind 9.10 nameserver settings (looks like fine tune for my needs), I already read the documentation how to set parameters, which parameters used for what in the named.conf file between the options{...}; but unfortunately I don't know how to check/read the actually values from command line.
The "named-checkconf -p" command only return that, what is written in the config files but not the nameserver's configuration.
Thanks for help!

Comment: I do not understand "what is written in the config files but not the nameserver's configuration" what do you mean? Also your question is not related to programming so offtopic here. You should be better on [sf] or [su], but read their help section to assess the topics discussed on each.

Answer (score 0):

Bind doesn't have a viewable "running config" that can be compared to the files-on-disk config. You can check the timestamp of your config file / zone data files and compare that to the service start time

```
[me@host ~]# service named status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status named.service
● named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-12-14 12:50:08 EST; 3 days ago
```

or

```
[me@host ~]# ps -o lstart= -p `pidof named`
Fri Dec 14 12:50:09 2018
```

If the file(s) have not changed since service start, then you know the file-based config matches the running config. If the files *have* changed ... unless you maintain your config files in some sort of source control where you can identify what the files looked like at a point in time, there is no way to identify what the difference is.

Maintaining your config files in some sort of source control has a lot of advantages -- identifying *who* changed something, being able to tell someone *when* their record that is no longer working got changed (and, bonus, a commit message referencing the request for the change), and being able to roll back when some change proves problematic.